# Run multiple query conditions from a list in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am making a python PyQt5 CSV comparison tool project and the user can add conditions for querying the pandas dataframe one by one before they are executed.

At the moment I have a nested list of conditions with each element containing the field, operation (==,!=,>,<), and value for comparison as strings. With just one condition I can use .query as it takes a string condition:

```
data.query('{} {} {}'.format(field,operation,value))
```

But as far as I can tell the formatting for multiple queries would use loc similar to this:

```
data.loc[(data.query('{} {} {}'.format(field[0],operation[0],value[0]))) & (data.query('{} {} {}'.format(field[1],operation[1],value[1]))) & ...]
```

Firstly I wanted to make sure my understanding of the loc function was correct (do I need a primary key at the end maybe?).

And secondly, how would I represent this multiple condition query with an unknown number of conditions set?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
conds = [
    f'{f} {o} {v}' for f, o, v in zip(field, operation, value)
]
data.query(' and '.join(conds))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: Not tested, more like a comment but put here for proper format:

`data.query` returns a dataframe, you can't just do `dataframe1 & dataframe2`. You would do something like

```
data.query(' AND '.join(['{} {} {}'.format(f, o, v) 
                         for f, o, v in zip(fields, operations, values)
                       ])
          )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and help with the query function, I didn't realise you could use the literal 'AND' as opposed to separation with &. From what I can see your code works when I have one condition but not multiple. One thing to mention is the the format of my conditions is actually [[f,o,v],[f,o,v]] not [f,f] [o,o] [v,v] (the example I gave was misleading) but I thing referencing the list instead of a zip is the same logic there. However, I'm getting an error with multiple conditions and the 'AND' separator: ``` SyntaxError: invalid syntax: id <100 AND id >95``` Any idea why?

Comment: Never mind, your answer works perfectly if you just change the 'AND' to '&' but it can still be a string! Thanks :)

Comment: @BarnieGill using `&` and `and` like that, in a query string are identical. Pandas literally replaces `&` (in that context) with `and` before processing it. I accidentally discovered that :)